# BigQuery Standard SQL: Setting a value to positive or negative infinity

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I note from the [docs for BigQuery Standard SQL Mathematical functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions) that we can test if a number "is infinity" using the `IS_INF()` function something like this:

```
WITH demo_tbl AS (
  SELECT 1 AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT 100 AS val
)

SELECT 
  val,
  IS_INF(val) as is_infinity
FROM demo_tbl
```

which outputs:

```
+---+-----+-------------+
|   | val | is_infinity |
+---+-----+-------------+
| 0 |   1 | False       |
| 1 | 100 | False       |
+---+-----+-------------+
```

but is it possible to **explicitly** set a value to be positive or negative infinity using some constant value or key word?

Perhaps something like this:

```
WITH demo_tbl AS (
  SELECT 1 AS val UNION ALL
  SELECT +inf AS val -- <-- THIS doesnt work
)

SELECT 
  val,
  IS_INF(val) as is_infinity
FROM demo_tbl
```

in order to give desired output similar to this:

```
+---+-----+-------------+
|   | val | is_infinity |
+---+-----+-------------+
| 0 |   1 | False       |
| 1 | inf | True        |
+---+-----+-------------+
```

I searched the documentation as best as I could and had a Google around this but couldn't turn up an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the value using `cast()`:

```
select is_inf(cast('Infinity' as float64))
```

or:

```
select is_inf(cast('inf' as float64))
```

Buried in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical) is:

> There is no literal representation of NaN or infinity, but the
>   following case-insensitive strings can be explicitly cast to float:
>
> - "NaN"
> - "inf" or "+inf"
> - "-inf"

Comment: @JaredCS . . . The question is tagged BigQuery and the database is in the title.  If you have a question about MySQL, then ask it as a *new* question and tag it appropriately.